# Bash ping command in if statement with square brackets does not work

Tags: bash, if-statement, ping

This works:

```
if ! ping -q -c 1 -W 1 google.com > /dev/null; then
   echo "google not reachable"
fi
```

but this does not work:

```
if [ ! `ping -q -c 1 -W 1 google.com > /dev/null` ]; then
    echo "google not reachable"
fi
```

Why does the second statement not work? Is it not basically the same?

Comment: "Square brackets" are not bash syntax. `[` is another name for the command `test`. If you couldn't run ```if test ! `ping ...` ```, you can't run ```if [ ! `ping ...` ]```.

Comment: Moreover, `> /dev/null` throws away the stdout of your command substitution's body, so there's no text for `[` to evaluate for emptiness/nonemptiness. (Not that it would work reliably without quotes regardless).

Comment: ```[ "`some command here`" ]``` tests whether `some command here` writes anything to stdout, because when you pass `test` only one argument, it checks whether that argument is empty. If you leave out the double quotes, by contrast, its behavior becomes effectively undefined, because the stdout of `some comand here` is subject to string splitting and glob expansion before `test` gets it..

Comment: (even though bash has a built-in version of `[` for performance reasons, your operating system probably provides a `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` that works exactly the same way, and which is probably a hardlink to the same executable as `/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/test`).

Comment: Without double-quotes around the backticked command, its output will be split into "words" and any words that contain wildcards will be expanded into a list of matching filenames; the result of this is passed to the `[` (`test`) command, which will attempt to treat it as some sort of expression. If the command prints something like "`a = a`", it makes sense as an expression, and `test` will evaluate that. If it prints something like "`PING google.com (216.58.193.78):`...", it's not going to make sense, and `[` will print an error. But since you redirected output, there won't be anything there.